# android studio Gradle startup failed,it is not working

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXeMO.png)

when i opened the android studio,i click a button in a dialog incautiously,and my gradle build got failed.And the log info was shown in this picture,how should i deal with it,thanks in adventure.

Comment: Try deleting `def signConf` containing line and syncing again

Comment: it is necessary to use "def signConf" to configurate jni

Comment: it did not work. I clicked a update button of dialog,and everything went wrong

Comment: Okay, in that case I do not know the answer to your question. Nevertheless, I suggest you re-ask it with more detail.

Comment: ok,thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Can you post complete build.gradle and what version of gradle are you using

Comment: here it is:distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uwkwi.png)

the source of the problem is this dialog,i clicked "update",and everything went wrong .Then i find the solution of this problem,change the gradle plugin version back is ok